# How can i get get expiry date and time from S3 pre-signed url

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, url, amazon-s3

I have stored a html file in S3 and I am generating a pre-signed URL for it with an expiry time of 4 hrs.
From the generated URL i want to extract the date and time of its expiry.
or any other way to to get its expiry date and time.

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the `X-Amz-Expires` or `Expires` query string in the URL.

It's a [UNIX timestamp](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Unix_time).